# Javascript - How to read a file while it is written

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

So say there's a log file, or in my case, a binary data file. (I'm pulling data to chart real-time stripcharts.) I'd like to read it all in and do whatever, and then have my FileReader trigger again once the local file has been updated. Is this functionality supported?

**Edit** If I understand [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#blobreader-state) correctly, then this isn't possible. Once done, the file is no longer being read. Say it ain't so! Any ways to continue reading from that point?

Comment: @jbabey Not true. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 8 of the File API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#file) specifies that File objects should have a `lastDateModified` property. You could check this field at a regular interval and if it has changed, reread the file. As you already found in the spec, it is unfortunately not possible to continue reading from where you left off.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What is your understanding of [slice](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#methodsandparams-blob)? Can I slice before reading? So that only a certain portion is read?

Comment: @savinger, I haven't used the File API extensively, but I'm confident that `Blob.slice()` is used to slice out chunks of data after the `Blob` has been read.